# Checking a key for particular value in redis

Tags: lua, redis

I need to check particular for particular key in a hash.

for example :  `HMSET myhash field1 "Hello" field2 "HI" field3 "Hey"`

Now i would like to check whether field3 has value as "Hey" or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Lua script? You can just do something like this:

```
if redis.call("hget", "myhash", "field3") == "Hey" then
    -- do what you want
end
```

Comment: Is there any best library to run lua scripts on redis from scala apart from jedis